# Convert Inpage file (.inp) to PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion

I have created a file (**Application Sample.inp**) in document writing tool **Inpage**.

Now, I want to convert above file into PDF without using third party tool.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you print the page? Assuming you're on Windows you can select **Microsoft Print to PDF** as printer.

Comment: **Inpage** does not have this option.

Comment: No print option (tried **Ctrl + P**)? (https://online2pdf.com/inp-to-pdf)
Can you export in another format maybe first?

Comment: You should be able to print to any printer available on your system, and this includes "Microsoft print to PDF" printer on Windows . [Here a blog that shows how to print Inpage files](http://inpageurdu.blogspot.com.br/2010/01/printing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your INP file.
2. Go to File >> Print or just press: Ctrl. + P.
3. Choose "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" as your printer.
4. Click on "OK" or "Print".
5. Select a destination for your XPS file and click on "Save".

or You might need to view this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443756/how-to-convert-inp-inpage-urdu-files-to-pdf